# Unable to boot device due to insufficient system resources [ DIFFERENT QUERY]

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, simulator

I know this error has been resolved before, but the reason I'm making this post is because my error has a significantly higher number of maxFiles and openFiles as compared to some of the other posts.

*Please see Simulator Help for information on adjusting system settings to allow more simulated devices to boot at once.
maxFiles: 12288, openFiles: 11711, enforcedFilesBuffer: 1868
Please see Simulator Help for information on adjusting system settings to allow more simulated devices to boot at once.
**maxFiles: 12288, openFiles: 11711, enforcedFilesBuffer: 1868***

Whereas the usual questions have no more than a few hundred such files shown in the error. How do I go about resolving this?

Comment: Did you try any of the suggested solutions? If so, what were the results?

Comment: Hey @Gereon, thank you for replying! The suggested solutions involved increasing the system capacity to 2500, since the warning in those questions suggested only a few hundred files were allowed as maxFiles and only a few hundred files were open. However, in my case, increasing system capacity to 2500 won't do much since the open files stand at over 11000. Out of fear of making unwanted permanent changes, I thought I'd ask a question instead of trying it out myself.